# How can I import .trc files in python?

Tags: python, file, csv, oscilloscope

I recently imported `.trc` files and can't open them on my python terminal. Is there any way to do it?

If not, is there any way to convert `.trc` files into `.csv`?

Comment: Which oscilloscope is producing these files? Is there anything on the manufacturer's website?